# NVarChar Variable Comparison

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

this is maybe really stupid. I don't really understand NVarChar comparison in T-SQL..
if i try something like that :

```
DECLARE @A NVARCHAR  = 'A';
DECLARE @AB NVARCHAR  = 'AB';
if @A = @AB
BEGIN
 PRINT N'A EQUALS AB';
END
```

'A EQUALS AB' is printed... Could you tell me why ?

Reading this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189863.aspx) does not really help...

thanks.

Comment: Because they're both `NVARCHAR(1)` which means they're both `N'A'`. Please stop this bad habit! https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Because you are declaring your nvarchar variables with no length specified, they are defaulting to a length of 1. Hence both variables only contain the first character `'A'`.

Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @A NVARCHAR(10)  = 'A';
DECLARE @AB NVARCHAR(10)  = 'AB';

if @A = @AB
BEGIN
 PRINT N'A EQUALS AB';
END
```

Comment: Agree with @Joe. When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.  I recently posted about it on my [blog](http://nilthakkar.blogspot.in/2012/01/specify-size-for-character-data-type.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @A NVARCHAR  = 'A'; -- IS a NVARCHAR(1) containg 'A' 
DECLARE @AB NVARCHAR  = 'AB'; -- IS also a NVARCHAR(1) containg 'A' 
DECLARE @AB2 NVARCHAR(2)  = 'AB'; -- IS a NVARCHAR(2) containg 'AB' 

if @A = @AB
BEGIN
 PRINT N'A EQUALS AB';
END


if @A != @AB2
BEGIN
 PRINT N'A NOT EQUALS AB';
END
```